# Array to String Conversion Error CodeIgniter using select_avg() function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've started learning the CodeIgniter framework recently and I'm developing this code which calculates the average feedback. Basically, a number of entries are there in the 'SERVICES' column and I want to return the average of these values and display it in a view as the average feedback. When I run this code, I get the following PHP error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion

Please tell me where I'm going wrong. Ibelieve that it's because my data passing is worng. How do I sort this problem in order to return the average value in the view?

Controller Code

```
function _admin_load_Home(){
    $data_admin=array(
        'avg_feedback' => $this->feedback->getAverage()
        );
    $this->load->view('header',$data_admin);
}
```

Model Code

```
function getAverage(){
    $avg_data = array(
        'SERVICE' => $this->db->select_avg('SERVICE')->from('feedback')- >get()->result()
    );
    return $avg_data;
}
```

View Code

```
  <tr>
  <th><?php echo $avg_feedback['SERVICE']; ?></th>
  </tr>
```

Note: 'SERVICE' is just one of the many 'feedback' table columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view get you array as

```
echo $data['SERVICE'][0]->SERVICE;
```

Comment: It's now giving the following errors: Undefined index: SERVICE and  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `print_r($avg_feedback);` in view and post its value

Comment: Array ( [SERVICE] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SERVICE] => 5.0000 ) ) )

Comment: Update: Worked on removing the foreach loop. Thank You so much.